# How to add environment variables to the bash opened by subprocess module?

Tags: python, subprocess

I need to use the wget in a Python script with the subprocess.call function, but it seems the "wget" command cannot be identified by the bash subprocess opened by python.

I have added the environment variable (the path where wget is):

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

to the ~/.bashrc file and the ~/.bash_profile file on my mac and guaranteed to have sourced them.
And the python script looks like:

```
import subprocess as sp
cmd = 'wget'
process = sp.Popen(cmd ,stdout=sp.PIPE, stdin=sp.PIPE, 
stderr=sp.PIPE, shell=True ,executable='/bin/bash')
(stdoutdata, stderrdata) = process.communicate()
print stdoutdata, stderrdata
```

The expected output should be like

```
wget: missing URL
Usage: wget [OPTION]... [URL]...
```

But the result is always

```
/bin/bash: wget: command not found
```

Interestingly I can get the help output if I type in wget directly in a bash terminal, but it never works in the python script. How could it be?

PS:

If I change the command to

```
cmd = '/usr/local/bin/wget'
```

then it works. So I am sure I got wget installed.

Comment: How are you running the Python script i.e. directly or via cron (or alike)?

Comment: Can you run wget from your shell? this code worked for me.

Comment: The code works for me too. If using wget isn't a hard requirement I'd suggest you check out `requests`: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

Comment: Thank you for your advices. I hope to do some ML data selection with Python first, download them and then do some analysis on the files, so i hope to add the downloading part into the script rather than open a bash to do it. As for the requests, I need to download TB level data so the requests would probably be too slow to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass an `env=` argument to the `subprocess` functions.

```
import os

myenv = os.environ.copy
myenv['PATH'] = '/usr/local/bin:' + myenv['PATH']
subprocess.run(..., env=myenv)
```

However, you probably want to avoid running a shell at all, and instead augment the `PATH` that Python uses to find the binary to run in the subprocess call.

```
import subprocess as sp
import os

os.environ['PATH'] = '/usr/local/bin:' + os.environ['PATH']
cmd = 'wget'
# use run instead of Popen
# don't needlessly use a shell
# and thus put [cmd] as a list
process = sp.run([cmd], stdout=sp.PIPE, stdin=sp.PIPE, 
stderr=sp.PIPE, 
    universal_newlines=True)
print(process.stdout, process.stderr)
```

[Running Bash commands in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python/51950538#51950538) explains the changes I made in more detail.

However, there is no good reason to use an external utility for this; Python `requests` does pretty everything `wget` does, often more naturally and with more control over what exactly it does.

Comment: Thank you, it does solve my question. It turns out that the IPython console does not share the environment variables with bash, and I do need to add it before calling a shell. As for the requests module, I need to download thousands of piciture files from a data base, and wget seems much faster than the requests module (which is based on Java after all)

Comment: `requests` is not based on Java. This is the first time I hear about speed problems with it; certainly you could switch to something like an `async` library if latency is your problem. Here's a nice blog about that: https://pawelmhm.github.io/asyncio/python/aiohttp/2016/04/22/asyncio-aiohttp.html